# vim-easy-align: How to align multiple characters with single command?

Tags: alignment, plugin-easy-align

I've created several keys and each key is working fine.
Want to find a way to do multiple alignments with single command. Like to create a key mapping, when it's running it can align the specific characters in sequence.
`map <leader>vga` first align all `space`, then align all `(`, last align all `)`.

```
example example (
   .a (a),
   .ab (ab),
   .abc (abc)
);
```

Expected output

```
example example (
   .a   ( a   ),
   .ab  ( ab  ),
   .abc ( abc )
);
```

easy_align_delimiters definitions:

```
    let g:easy_align_delimiters = {
...
    \ '(': {
    \     'pattern':       '[(]',
    \     'left_margin':   1,
    \     'right_margin':  1,
    \     'stick_to_left': 0
    \   },
    \ ')': {
    \     'pattern':       '[)]',
    \     'left_margin':   1,
    \     'right_margin':  0,
    \     'stick_to_left': 0
    \   },
...
```

Comment: But that would not work anyway, would it? First if you align with `space`, and then you align with `(` then the previous alignment would be destroyed.

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from an example

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, Previous alignment won't get lost if you align with another character.

Comment: I think your previous comment was meant for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below shortcut and function will do the job.

```
map <leader>vga :call Vhdl_GA_All()<CR>

" Alignment
function! Vhdl_GA_All()
   exe "normal! \e"
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign *<space>"
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign ("
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign )"
endfunction
```